# Position and Height trouple with layered divs using z-index

Tags: css, css-position, z-index

I need some help finessing a layout I’m working on.

Here is a link to the current status of the site:
http://sometimesyoubreakaclarinet.com/

What you’ll see is a large pink area behind the gray content area, it is roughly a third down the page. For some reason, it is only forming to 100% of the height/width of the browser when I actually want it to match the height of the content. How do I get the height to fill down to fit to the content, in the same way the gray content area is already doing?

Secondly, I want this pink area to begin at the end of the background banner image at the top rather than where it is now. How do I achieve this? Do I need to change the position from relative to something else?

The goal here is to have the pink area flow over the banner image and title; something like what is outlined here:
http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-collapsing-header-effect

I’ve include what I think is the relevant CSS code below, possibly I’ve left something important out but you should be able to locate the CSS file on the link above if necessary.

```
#menu           { width: 100%; height: 32px; margin: auto; padding: 6px auto 0; top:0px; z-index: 10;
                  position: fixed; text-decoration: none; background: rgba(44,44,44,0.95); }
#photograph     { width: 100%; margin: 0 auto; background: #8a2dc7 url('img/header-2014-apr-1200.jpg') fixed center top no-repeat;
                  background-position: center top; background-size: 100%; min-height: 250px; height: 250px; top:0px; 
                  position: fixed; }    
#sitetitle      { width: 100%; height: auto; margin: 0 auto; padding: 25px 0 0 0; background: transparent; position: fixed; }   #deck           { width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 100%; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; position: relative; 
                  background: transparent; z-index: 4; }
#card           { width: 800px; height: auto; margin: 170px auto 0; padding: 10px 18px; 
                  text-decoration: none; background: #2c2c2c; }
#curtain        { width: 100%; height: auto; min-height: 100%; margin: 220px auto 0; padding: 0; position: relative; 
                  background: #f12fde; z-index: 2; }
```

Hopefully someone can help me figure this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

does this fix your issue? Change the css of #curtain to..

```
#curtain {
    width: 800px;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background: #f12fde;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that might have worked. What I did was remove #curtain altogether, then use a negative value for top with #card. Now, I'm wondering if it'd be possible to add a sticky footer.